# TYPO3 11: configure route for form and action buttons

Tags: forms, routes, frontend, typo3-11.x

I have a simple test form in a partial. This contains two action buttons.

```
<h1>testForm</h1>
<div>
    <f:form action="foo" controller="JobProfile">
        <f:form.textfield name="mystring" value="mystring"/>
        <f:form.button type="submit" name="action" value="foo" >Foo </f:form.button>
        <f:form.button type="submit" name="action" value="bar"> Bar </f:form.button><br />
        <f:form.submit value="Simple" />
    </f:form>
</div>
```

The switching works well. Depending on the click, I reach either the FooAction() or the BarAction().

The following definition can be found in the YAML file for the page configuration:

```
routeEnhancers:
  adjobPluginOne:
    type: Extbase
    limitToPages:
      - 15
      - 68
    extension: myext
    plugin: MyPlugin
    routes:
      -
        routePath: '/foo/{me}'
        _controller: 'MyController::foo'
        _arguments:
          me: myobject
      -
        routePath: '/bar/{me}'
        _controller: 'MyController::bar'
        _arguments:
          me: myobject
```

I can call both actions correctly by clicking on the buttons. But I get a link for the result with the following form:
 `https://foobar.ddev.site/.../neue-stelle?tx_myext_myplugin%5Baction%5D=foo&tx_myext_myplugin%5Bcontroller%5D=MyController&cHash=9eb1fdd49624970dfc26ce06235a73c8`

I expect something like that, with uid=12 for mystring-object.
`https://foobar.ddev.site/.../neue-stelle/foo/12`